# Kafka java Producer - Connection to localhost:9092 could not be established

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am playing with a Kafka for Java tutorial. I have concocted the following code:

**Producer class**

```
public class ProducerDemo {
    static String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create producer properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        // create producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

        // create ProducerRecord
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("first_topic", "hello world!");

        // send data
        producer.send(record);

        producer.close();
    }
}
```

**Gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.greem666.kafka'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.8.0'

    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.30'
}
```

I have a kafka_2.13-2.8.0 Zookeeper and one Broker running in a WSL2 instance on the same Win10 machine. When trying to play with console Consumer and console Producer in WSL2, it all works fine.

However, when I try to run the above Java class, I get this:

**Java logs**

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.8.0
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: ebb1d6e21cc92130
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1623940023993
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Does it have something to do with Kafka Zookeeper and Broker running in a WSL2?

Comment: `localhost` is not exactly the same as `127.0.0.1`. Did you try actually using `localhost`?

Comment: Yes, have tried both 127.0.0.1:9092, localhost:9092. When these did not work, even tried 0.0.0.0:9092, but to same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your code in WSL2, or you need to setup a port forward from the hypervisor to your Windows local network adapter in order for `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` to work (assuming you didn't modify any host file)